# What does Depends() do in FastAPI?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, fastapi

I'm trying to understand dependency injection in FastAPI. Why is Depends() needed in the following example from the docs? What does Depends() do?

```
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


async def common_parameters(q: str | None = None, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return {"q": q, "skip": skip, "limit": limit}


@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(commons: Annotated[dict, Depends(common_parameters)]):
    return commons
```

Why does it not work to simply call the common_parameters function like so?

```
@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(commons: Annotated[dict, common_parameters()]):
    return commons
```

Comment: Your example would just result in a dict being expected as a JSON body instead of as GET parameters (i.e. it doesn't express the dependency on the parameters, just that a dict is expected instead). And if it had worked - you'd just have called the function getting the default parameter values back, instead of FastAPI being able to fill out the arguments from the query string. The `Depends` keyword makes FastAPI resolve the dependency - and their hierarchies - for each request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depends is mean Dependency Injection

in fastapi source code

[image: Depends definition]

it is need a callable dependency,which is a function.
in your code `common_parameters()` it is not callable,it return a dict,not function.

function `common_parameters` need fastapi incoming parameter,then `common_parameters` parse parameter, return result